# Free programming editor w/ syntax highlighting for iBook G4 running Mac OS X 10.4.11 (PowerPC)

Tags: development, text-editor, powerpc, ibook

I am looking for a free programming editor for my iBook G4.

I was going to to get the lightswitch trial until I looked at the sys requirements (needs Intel CPU).

Can someone please point me to a free editor that will work with a G4 iBook running 10.4.11 and supports html, css, javascript, php and c# syntax highlighting?

Comment: Lightswitch also requires Windows...

Comment: yes... at the time, I was very near ready to install some linux with wine should all else fail. And very tired. But you are right of course, it requires Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/TextWrangler/) will do. It's a freeware, but you probably need to search for an older version.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm going to try the linked VIM from the other post first, but if that doesn't work I'll start looking for legacy TextWrangler versions and post a direct link at the end of the topic if I find one.

Answer (score 1):

- [VIM](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/)
- [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org) (Java app but I like it)

Comment: *rejoices* A direct link to a download that will work with my system. Thank you!